# C# can't find assembly which is already loaded

Tags: c#, .net

I am writing an application which uses plugins. Plugins are class libraries which lie in Plug-ins directory. My app loads these libraries via LoadFrom. Some of them have dependencies in the form of libraries which lie in the same Plug-ins directory. When I try to create instance of class from one of plugins via Activator.CreateInstance i recieve an exception 'Unable to find assembly' (this is dependency assembly of plugin), but this assembly is already loaded (!) along with plugins and It is visible in ProcessExplorer. 
I can't uderstand in what my trouble is.

Comment: Can you provide a short but complete example which demonstrates the problem?

Comment: Why donot you share the code? It will be easier to crack the issue.

Comment: In addition to what Jon suggested, you should also provide the version of the CLR you are using, along with the OS (32bit/64bit). Also, are you using multiple application domains and do you explicitly set a [LoaderOptimization](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.loaderoptimization.aspx) value? We had some weird issues w.r.t. all of that using CLR 2.0 on 32 bit vs. 64 bit.

Comment: My OS is 64bit, but I don't know how to learn a CLR version :(

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had similar problems and they were usually solved by changing target framework in the project properties...

Answer (score 6):

Your problem might be, that de loaded assembly **isn't the same version** as the request one. .Net Runtime maps the Assembly after their name and after their Version if the name equals and the Version differes you get an exception if the other one is loaded, which says "Assembly cann't be found" or something like that. The Problem is, that the assembly could not be matched properly. But there is a solution:
Take a look at the [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd153782.aspx#avoid_loading_multiple_versions) for further information about that Problem.

### Solution for that problem:

1. If you have to load 2 Versions of that assembly try helping the runtime by implementing the [AssemblyResolve Event](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.appdomain.assemblyresolve.aspx) Samples are also [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.appdomain.assemblyresolve.aspx).
2. Try using the [AssemblyBindLogViewer](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/e74a18c4%28v=vs.71%29.aspx) to determine the dependencies of your plugins and to crosscheck your problem.

> I recommend implementing the event anyways if you deal with plugins,
>   so you can log all assembly requests of that AppDomain.

You will find furhter information about runtime behavior and assembly loading [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/yx7xezcf%28v=vs.71%29.aspx)
Hope i could help, please give us feedback about your solution!

### Configuring the Plugin Folder

1. **Load the Plugins into a [seperat AppDomain](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/c8hk0245.aspx)** which has the pluginfolder as ApplicationBase
   To configure AppDomains [see](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.appdomainsetup.aspx). **This is the recomendet solution** to load Plugins, becaus you can define the [security](http://www.15seconds.com/issue/040121.htm) level of the AppDomain (Sandboxing)
2. **Extend your current [AppDomains PrivatePath](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.appdomain.appendprivatepath.aspx)**, so it also searches the Assemblies in this Path. This method is Obsolete!(but does it's job)

Comment: `AssemblyResolve` is the solution - the problem is that the runtime doesn't know anything about his Plugins folder and so is ignoring it when doing its own dependency loading.  This applies to DLLs that are already loaded through `LoadFrom` - `LoadFrom` can generally be bad.

Comment: Added an alternative solution to define the plugin folder.

Comment: AppendPrivatePath helps...Thanks.

Comment: You are welcome, please tag the question as answered :-), Thank!

Answer (score 1):

You should provide Full Path of assembly files.

```
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        var asmFileName = "test.dll"; // Your plug-in file name
        var asmPath = AppDomain.CurrentDomain.BaseDirectory; // Your assemblies's root folder
        var asmFullPath = System.IO.Path.Combine(asmPath, asmFileName);
        var asm = System.Reflection.Assembly.LoadFrom(asmFullPath);
    }
}
```